# How to set cookie attribute HTTPOnly and Secure to true for WAS 7.0 and Java?

Tags: cookies

I have set Restrict cookie to HTTPS Sessions and also add property for addhttpponly in the WAS but still my cookie secure and HTTPOnly flags not appearing in Response from Http or not by developer tools(F12)??